# Firestore Storage file naming

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

In the examples in [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files), the reference paths include a file extension, but as I understand it [from here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#add_file_metadata), it has nothing to do with the way Storage infers the file type. Does adding the extension to the path have any benefits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Storage has no need/use for the extension, but your application/platform may. For example, Windows systems often assign meaning to a file based on its extension.

In the end, it is up to you whether you want to store the file names with their extensions. But as said: Cloud Storage does nothing specific with the extension and just treats it as part of the filename.

---

If you remove the filename extension from the uploaded file, but keep a mime type in the file's metadata, you can derive the filename extensions from that mime type when needed.

---

The Firebase SDK can list files, but not with any pattern matching criteria. As far as I can see the native RPC/REST protocols of Cloud Storage don't support such filtering either, so any SDKs that *do* offer wildcard-like filters seem to do so in client-side code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For now, I only upload pictures, which are shown in my app, so I don't need the extension. I'm just worried about future possibilities - will I be able to retrieve the types from the metadata Firebase saves on upload if I'll need it? or should I take care of it manually (find correct extension and add to path) to avoid possible problems?

Comment: Thanks! The useful part is actually in this last comment - the fact that it's possible to map the mime type from the metadata. I suppose it is possible to do that in the process of the file download and add it to the downloaded name. If that's true, and also it is impossible to get a list of files based on a regex (like '*.jpg'), which I didn't find any API for (do you know if it is possible?), so I see no use case in which saving the extension has any benefit. Please edit the answer to refer to these 2 topics, for others to get the hole picture, and i'll accept it :)

Comment: I added some additional information to the answer